# iOS redirect to new ViewCOntroller does not load all UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to implement the google map module to set the control parameters before adding the mARKER

The wayout is to initiate acquire the result of  new viewController via NSBUndles. My desire goal is to redirect to the sameViewController as expected result.

But when it comes to the implementation  , it loads the actual result:

Expected result:
[image]
Actual result
[image]

Would you please tell me what other details for instantiate a new ViewController with all UI elements being set as expected viewControllers? I swear that the new ViewController has all require elements being set on?

The actual console message writes:

```
2014-06-18 17:50:37.766 marker[1469:60b] Text=2014-06-18 17:50:36
2014-06-18 17:50:41.102 marker[1469:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x17daf180>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SliderViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3102dfd3 0x3b7dcccf 0x33d1bfb7 0x7e155 0x31031584 0x30f7c0db 0x30f7f873 0x231ffb 0x310300f1 0x30f7f7b8 0x20d6bb 0x138133 0x155319 0x339d000d 0x3387b503 0x33c22af5 0x33842373 0x33840abb 0x30ff92a5 0x30ff6c49 0x30ff6f8b 0x30f61f0f 0x30f61cf3 0x35e66663 0x338ad16d 0x7f4ed 0x3bce9ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The below is my code

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{


sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];
    sliderVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Code for new viewCOntroller (.m) only:

```
#import "SliderViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import "EFCircularSlider.h"

@interface SliderViewController (){
    NSString *valueV;
    NSString *valueC;
}

@end

@implementation SliderViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _uiSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    _uiSlider.maximumValue = 100.0;
    [_uiSlider removeConstraints:_uiSlider.constraints];
    [_uiSlider setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    float value  = M_PI * -0.5 ;
   _uiSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(value);

    CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectMake(60, 300, 100, 100);
    EFCircularSlider* circularSlider = [[EFCircularSlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
    [circularSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:circularSlider];
    [circularSlider setCurrentValue:10.0f];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)valueChanged:(EFCircularSlider*)slider {
    self.uiValue2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", slider.currentValue ];
    valueC =  self.uiValue2.text;
    if(slider.currentValue  > 20.0 && slider.currentValue  < 30.0  ){
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
       // AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}


- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    [self writeToTextFile:valueV :valueC];
    self.uiValue.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , 0.00];
    [self.uiSlider setValue:0.00];
  }



-(void) writeToTextFile:(NSString*) values : (NSString*) values2 {
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/slider.txt",documentsDirectory];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", values , @"\n" , values2 , @"\n" ];
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:YES
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];
      NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
    [self displayContent];
}

-(void) displayContent{
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/slider.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                    usedEncoding:nil
                                                           error:nil];
    //use simple alert from my library (see previous post for details)

    NSLog(@"%@",content);
    // [self showEmail:fileName];
}


- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , slider.value];
    self.uiValue.text = newValue;
    valueV  = self.uiValue.text;
    if(slider.value > 30 && slider.value < 50){
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
        //AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the new view controller, you have to instantiate it with a nib file, something like:

`sliderVC = [[SliderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SliderViewController" bundle:nil]`

or if you use storyboards:

`sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];`

Otherwise there is no connection to the file that you created in Interface Builder and iOS doesn't know what UI elements to load for this view controller.

Update: this is where you have to set the string:

[image]

Comment: code edited 
It shows the following exception that
Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x17daf180>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SliderViewController''

Comment: yeah, you need to use the identifier that you have set in the storyboard for this view controller instead of the string _SliderViewController_

Comment: Do you mean setting the Storyboard ID under the Identity for this ViewController ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Nikolas Burk answer - if you have all your Viewcontrollers on one storyboard, you can instantiate them like this :

```
MyClassViewController *next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"name"];
```

The `name` is set in InterfaceBuilder.